# How to make a web server perform function on a regular basis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net + MVC to bulid a website.

There is some function I need it to run once a day or once an hour.

I have used tool Timer in Framework for a similar function,but how to perform this on a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a task scheduler like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), which can run in a web environment.

For this to work, you need to make sure your webapp is running at the time your job should be started (although Hangfire will properly handle that case), which means using some kind of heartbeat monitoring or the "Always running" setting in IIS.